# Finding the median of a set of data from a cumulative frequency graph GCSE level

Tags: mathematical-statistics, median

200 students estimate the volume, V of a classroom.
The cumulative frequency diagram shows their results.

You are told at GCSE level to find the median by dividing 200 by 2, finding it on the y axis and reading off the value of the estimated volume on the x axis.  Why do you not find the average of the estimated volume for the 100th and 101st student?

Comment: Translation for international audience: GCSE is a secondary school examination in Britain and some other countries taken around age 16. In Britain it commonly marks the last shared point of students' mathematical education, except that some flavours are even less demanding than others.

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition of a cumulative probability distribution for sample size $n$ is asymmetric, probabilities running from $1/n$ to $n/n$, so $0$ is not a plotted point but $1$ is. With this convention the median for even $n$ would (or should) plot just above $0.5$, but the discrepancy is only noticeable for a small sample size. If there were only $10$ values, the median would by this convention be plotted at $0.55$ cumulative probability, as it is at rank $5.5$. $100.5/200 = 0.5025$ is hardly discernible from $0.5$ except on a very large graph.

The difference is thus between a graphical approximation good and practical for at least moderate sample size and a numerical convention, which is exact in its own terms. (Mathematical groups are taught that the taking the midpoint  $y_{(n/2)} + y_{(n/2 + 1)}$ when $n$ is even in sample $y$ is a convention, and non-mathematical groups that it is a rule.)

Other way round, on quantile plots rather than cumulative distribution plots, it is common to plot ordered values (quantiles wide sense) against so-called plotting  positions, usually but not universally one member of a family $(i - a) / (n -2a + 1)$ for rank $i = 1, \dots, n$ and some $a$. Common choices for $a$ are $a = 0, a = 1/2, a = 1/3$. With such recipes, plotting positions are all symmetric about $0.5$, so that the median should always plot at probability $0.5$, either if it is a single value for odd sample size or if it is a midpoint for even sample size. For example, given a sample size of $200$, $(100.5 - 0.5) / (200 - 1 + 1), 100.5/201, $ and $(100.5 - 1/3) / (201 - 2/3)$ all reduce to $0.5$.